# FileOutputStream with java 8 and try with resource gettng error

Tags: java, java-8, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream, try-with-resources

I am writing serialization code for eclipse I am trying to use FileOutputStream with try-with-resource but I am getting a error message : "Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7"
And as fix Eclipse is showing the message "Change project compliance and JRE to 1.7". This is a new error for me, please help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee employeeOut = null;

    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Employee.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos) ){

    }
}
```

I want to compile this class.

Comment: ok so I cannot use it in the try-with resource ?

Comment: As a correction use InputStream fos = new FileInputStream("Employee.ser")

Comment: ok corrected the code, but my problem not solved.

Comment: Is this a maven project?

Comment: yes this is a maven project

Comment: Eclipse is telling you how to fix this already. See this short gif demonstrating how to use this hint: https://imgur.com/BIWmiOX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project setup is wrong. To fix that, right click your project, then select Properties.
Select "Build Path", and the tab "Libraries".
[image: Build Path]
Select JRE System Library, and click "Edit...".
[image: JRE System Library]
Select "Execution environment" "JavaSE-1.8", then "Finish".
Now select "Java Compiler" on the left.
[image: Java Compiler]
Make sure "Use compilance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.8' on the 'Java Build Path'" is checked.

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem in Eclipse, right click on the project, then
properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Library > JRE System Library and then follow the menu selection.

You can select the JDK installation location.